# Apply Perfect-Scrollbar to all elements

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, perfect-scrollbar

I used perfec-scrollbar and works fine like this

```
Ps.initialize(east, {
    wheelSpeed: 2
});
```

and now i want change all scroll-bars to perfect-scrollbar, how can i do that?
something like :

```
Ps.initialize("*", {
    wheelSpeed: 2
});
```

But this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, set class `scrollbar` for your div containers. And initialize these in `each` loop:

```
jQuery('.scrollbar').each(function(){
    Ps.initialize(jQuery(this), {
        wheelSpeed: 2
    });
})
```

Comment: you mean this?  

 $("div").addClass("scrollbar");

        jQuery('.scrollbar').each(function(){
            Ps.initialize(jQuery(this), {
                wheelSpeed: 2
            });
        })

scrollbar added to all div elements but doesn't change to perfect-scrollbar

Comment: its a jsf code that renders html but a sample for id="east" that i used before is here:  <br/>  <div id="east" class="ui-layout-east ui-widget-content ui-corner-all pe-layout-pane-content admin-right-sidebar
 scrollbar ui-layout-pane ui-layout-pane-east" data-combinedposition="east" style="position: absolute; 
margin: 0px; left: auto; right: 0px; top: 91px; bottom: 0px; height: 342px; z-index: 0; width: 240px; display: block; visibility: visible;">
@Vitali